# Handling unicode directory and filenames in Perl on Windows

Tags: perl, encoding, directory, tk-toolkit

I have an encoding problem with Perl and Windows. On a Windows 7 running Perl (strawberry 5.16) and a simple TK GUI I need to open files and/or access directories with non-english characters in their name/path. For opening files I've come out with this solution which seems to work fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::Unicode::File;
use Encode;
use Tk;

my $mw = Tk::MainWindow->new;
my $tissue_but = $mw->Button(
    -text => 'Open file',
    -command =>  [ \&select_unicode_file ],
);
$tissue_but->grid( -row => 3, -column => 1 );
Tk::MainLoop();

sub select_unicode_file{
my $types = [ ['Txt', '.txt'],
          ['All Files',   '*'],];
my $input_file= $mw->getOpenFile(-filetypes => $types);
my $fh = Win32::Unicode::File->new;
if ($fh->open('<', $input_file)){
  while (my $line = $fh->readline()){
    print "\n$line\n";
  }
   close $fh;
}
 else{
  print "Couldn't open file: $!\n";
}
}
```

This correctly opens files such as Поиск/Поиск.txt

What I CANNOT do is to simply get a directory path and than process it. I think I should use use Win32::Unicode::Dir but I really can't understand the documentation.

It should be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::Unicode::Dir;
use Encode;
use Tk;

my $mw = Tk::MainWindow->new;
my $tissue_but = $mw->Button(
    -text => 'Open file',
    -command =>  [ \&select_unicode_directory ],
);
$tissue_but->grid( -row => 3, -column => 1 );
Tk::MainLoop();

sub select_unicode_directory{
my $dir = $mw->chooseDirectory( );
my $wdir = Win32::Unicode::Dir->new;
my $dir = $wdir->open($dir) || die $wdir->error;
my $dir_complete = "$dir/a.txt";
open (MYFILE, $dir_complete );
    while (<MYFILE>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
}
close (MYFILE); 
}
```

Comment: `open` takes bytes. Use Win32API::File's `CreateFileW` to open the file. IIRC, you'll have to pass it through `encode('UTF-16le', "$qfn\0")` first.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get it. How can I get the path in the above code using Win32::Unicode::Dir->new ?

Comment: ah, so you have two problems. Sorry, can't look into it right now.

Comment: any chance to get an answer?

Comment: hum, don't know anything Tk, really. I can give it a try this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical error in:

```
my $dir = $wdir->open($dir) || die $wdir->error;
my $dir_complete = "$dir/a.txt";
```

`$wdir->open('path')` returns an object, not a string. You can't use it like a path. But that is not the worst of it. Sadly, it seems like the Tk implementation does not yet have support for Unicode file names (including chooseDirectory). I guess you will have to write a custom dir selector, but I'm not sure it's even possible.

This is capable of listing files in an ascii-chars folder (and ->fetch can list utf-8 files), and crashes when opening a folder with utf-8 chars. Well, to be fair it crashes when opening `??????`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::Unicode::Dir;
use Win32::Unicode::Console;
use Encode;
use Tk;

my $mw = Tk::MainWindow->new;
my $tissue_but = $mw->Button(
    -text => 'Select dir',
    -command =>  [ \&select_unicode_directory ],
);
$tissue_but->grid( -row => 3, -column => 1 );
Tk::MainLoop();

sub select_unicode_directory {
    my $wdir = Win32::Unicode::Dir->new;
    my $selected = $mw->chooseDirectory(-parent =>$mw);
       # http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tk/pod/chooseDirectory.pod#CAVEATS
       $selected = encode("utf-8", $selected);
    print "selected: $selected\n";

    $wdir->open($selected) || die $wdir->error;

    print "\$mw->chooseDirectory:    $selected\n";
    print "\$wdir->open(\$selected): $wdir\n";


# CRASH HERE, presumably because winders can't handle '?' in a file (dir) name
    for ($wdir->fetch) {
# http://search.cpan.org/~xaicron/Win32-Unicode-0.38/lib/Win32/Unicode/Dir.pm
        next if /^\.{1,2}$/;
        my $path = "$selected/$_";
        if (file_type('f', $path)) { print "file: $path\n"; } 
        elsif (file_type('d', $path)) { print " dir: $path\n"; }
    }
    print "closing \n";
    $wdir->close || die $wdir->error;

}
```

### Sample out (opening Поиск/):

Both samples below were run using: Strawberry Perl 5.12.3 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

```
selected: C:/cygwin/home/jaroslav/tmp/so/perl/open-file-tk/?????
$mw->chooseDirectory:    C:/cygwin/home/jaroslav/tmp/so/perl/open-file-tk/?????
$wdir->open($selected): Win32::Unicode::Dir=HASH(0x2e38158)
>>> perl crash <<<
```

### Sample out (opening parent of Поиск):

```
selected: C:/cygwin/home/jaroslav/tmp/so/perl/open-file-tk
$mw->chooseDirectory:    C:/cygwin/home/jaroslav/tmp/so/perl/open-file-tk
$wdir->open($selected): Win32::Unicode::Dir=HASH(0x2b92c10)
file: C:/cygwin/home/jaroslav/tmp/so/perl/open-file-tk/.select_uni_dir.pl.swp
file: C:/cygwin/home/jaroslav/tmp/so/perl/open-file-tk/o
file: C:/cygwin/home/jaroslav/tmp/so/perl/open-file-tk/o.dir
file: C:/cygwin/home/jaroslav/tmp/so/perl/open-file-tk/select_uni_dir.pl
file: C:/cygwin/home/jaroslav/tmp/so/perl/open-file-tk/select_uni_file.pl
 dir: C:/cygwin/home/jaroslav/tmp/so/perl/open-file-tk/Поиск
```

### Conclusion

The Tk dir selector returns ????? instead of Поиск. While looking for a way to enable Unicode in Tk, I found this:

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tk/pod/UserGuide.pod#Perl/Tk_and_Unicode :

> (...) Unfortunately, there are still places in Perl ignorant of 
>   Unicode. One of these places are filenames. Consequently, the file selectors 
>   in Perl/Tk do not handle encoding of filenames properly. Currently they 
>   suppose that filenames are in iso-8859-1 encoding, at least on Unix systems. 
>   As soon as Perl has a concept of filename encodings, then Perl/Tk will also 
>   implement such schemes.

So at first glance it seems what you're trying to do is impossible (unless you 
write or find a custom dir-selector). Actually, it may not be a bad idea to 
submit this bug, because the GUI **did show** "Поиск" so the error is in the return value.

Comment: in reality, "Perl ignorant of Unicode" use 'C' (raw) as character table, very similar to 'iso-8859-1', but 'C' table is different on different platforms. We can understand this as "local raw 8-byte system character table'.